# Need to know how to search multiple keyword in a same field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I was working to search multiple keywords in the same field. I found with wildcart query but its taking long time or sometimes crash my server.

message : *Hi abc, your code is 56712386*

`{ "query": { "wildcard": { "message" : "*abc*123" } } }`

I need something which will give instant result without wasting time or utilizing complete resource.

Comment: Share the mapping please. and One more question, the keywords you will be searching are separated by space or some other separator ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you are looking for.

- searching only part of a word
- searching multiple words

Before I go ahead and explain how its done, you may want to understand how elasticsearch works internally.

Elasticsearch would break down the sentence (of a field) into tokens and stores these tokens in inverted index. This process is called [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

So now whatever query you would have, it would only work if the tokens you are searching for is available in the inverted index.

Basically it all boils down to what tokens are stored in inverted index.

Now from implementation perspective Elasticsearch implements the concept of [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) using [Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html). I'd suggest you to start reading the links to understand better.

For the sake of simplicity, I'd only mention that in order to search for *a part* of a word, you might want to create a custom Analyzer using [NGram Tokens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) are.

I've mentioned the link so that you can refer that to understand what it is.

I've created a sample mapping and the query to get what you are looking for, for the document you have mentioned in the question:

### Mapping:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 4,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Document:

```
POST myindex/_doc/1
{
  "message": "Hi abc, your code is 56712386"
}
```

### Query Request:

**[Using query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)**

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "message",
      "query": "abc AND 123"
    }
  }
}
```

**[Using Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)**

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how I've used the above queries. In query string you can search multiple words using bool operators `AND` and `OR` while in Bool query, you can use `must` and `should` that would be like logical AND and logical OR.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards or even using wildcards in querystrings dont scale well since you are potentially checking the whole index. You are asking a lot of the search engine at query time. You can use the nGram filter, to do the processing at index-time not search time.

You can check this link for ngram tokenizer.

https://gist.github.com/karmi/988923